# Serpent Sbox transformation

Tags: cryptography

Consider I have this sample key

```
15FC0D48 D7F8199C BE399183 4D96F327 10000000 00000000  00000000  00000000
w-8         w-7      w-6       w-5     w-4       w-3       w-2       w-1
```

Creating first K0 Key Schedule pair

```
(k0,k1,k2,k3)=S3(w0,w1,w2,w3)=K0
```

using this formula for Serpent Key Schdule

```
wi=(wi-8 xor wi-5 xor wi-3 xor wi-1 xor phi xor i)<<<11
```

1) i=0

```
w0=w-8 xor w-5 xor w-3 xor w-1 xor 9e3779b9 xor 0<<<11=15FC0D48 xor 4D96F327 xor 00000000 xor 00000000 xor 9e3779b9 xor 0 <<<11=EC3EB632
```

2) i=1

```
w1=w-7 xor w-4 xor w-2 xor w0 xor 9e3779b9 xor 1<<<11=D7F8199C xor 10000000 xor  00000000 xor EC3EB632 xor 9e3779b9 xor  1<<<11=8EB0B5AF
```

3) i=2

```
w2=w-6 xor w-3 xor w-1 xor w1 xor 9e3779b9 xor 2<<<11=BE399183 xor 00000000 xor 00000000 xor 8EB0B5AF xor 9e3779b9 xor  2<<<11=F2ECBD75
```

4) i=3

```
w3=w-5 xor w-2 xor w0 xor w2 xor 9e3779b9 xor 3<<<11=4D96F327 xor 00000000  xor EC3EB632 xor F2ECBD75 xor 9e3779b9 xor 3<<<11=9C0ED66B
```

For k0 will be created by Sbox3

```
S3(w0,w1,w2,w3)
EC3EB632
binary form:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
11|10|11|00|00|11|11|10|10|11|01|10|00|11|00|10|
after Sbox3
11101010001111001110110001101100
EA3CEC6C


8EB0B5AF
binary form:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
10|00|11|10|10|11|00|00|10|11|01|01|10|10|11|11
after Sbox3
10110110101100101000111001001111
B6B28E4F

F2ECBD75
binary form:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
11|11|00|10|11|10|11|00|10|11|11|01|01|11|01|01
after Sbox3
11010110011111101111001111001001
D67EF3C9

9C0ED66B
binary form:
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12 13 14 15
10|01|11|00|00|00|11|10|11|01|01|10|01|10|10|11
after Sbox3
10111011010111001001110001100010
BB5C9C62

k0={EA3CEC6C B6B28E4F D67EF3C9 BB5C9C62}
```

I use my solution in C# for SBOX transformation:

```
String key="10011100000011101101011001101011";
prek="";
Uint32 k;
for (int i = sboxpos; i < sboxpos + 1; i++)
{
for (int i2 = 0; i2 < 16; i2++)
{
prek += key.Substring(sbox[i, i2] * 2, 2); //Multiplying on 2 to move byte on appropriate position, as in my example above I transform hex to binary it have 32bits, but Sbox'es moves only bytes. So e.g. the 15's byte is 15*2=30's position plus 2 characters
}
}
k = Convert.ToUInt32(prek, 2);
```

My question is am I doing Key schedule of Serpent right, as in other implementation they uses an &, operands in Sbox'es. Will I have same result by applying Sbox transformation in my code above? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest thing to do is to test this against the reference implementation in the AES submission package, it logs quite a lot.

Comment: There is no test vectors for Sbox Transformation. And also no test vectors for key schedule. In many sources all definition of Serpent is different,someone tells that it needs to use BigEndian/LittleEndian, someone no. It's very uncomfortable to implement Serpent with out proper examples, even there is no sample for Key Schedule all I forced to do is understand as I read.

Comment: Is it possible to upload before/after Sbox Tranformation table, so that I could test that my function proceeds correctly. E.g. EFDE1111(before Sbox) ADC21111(after Sbox). Thanks!

Comment: I have reviewed official submission package of Serpent and noticed that in Sbox they use AND(&) OR(|) operands.Why they do it, as according to tables Sbox just moves bits. Here is how I understand Sbox transform:Lets have this HEX B0:EC3EB632 In binary(I mark them as bytes 0-15, 16*2=32bytes: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 11|10|11|00|00|11|11|10|10|11|01|10|00|11|00|10| After Sbox3 Appliance (byte 0 goes on 0 position (11), byte 15 goes on 1st position(10), byte 11 goes on 2nd position(10) and so on until I reach byte 14: 11101010001111001110110001101100 (EA3CEC6C) Is it correct?

Comment: I personally don't know. If you have theoretical questions about serpent you should ask them on [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com). If I remember then I took a quick look at the serpent AES submission (it's separated to diskette images :) ) and it contains a Java implementation with a lot of logging - it wouldn't be too hard to add some maybe?

Comment: Yes I looked it, but their view on Sbox is very unsimillar to mine. I also know that Serpent uses Sboxes from DES, but in DES we take LSB and RSB to get row number than LSB+1 to RSB-1 (remaining part) is column number and I write this Row/Column number in binary that the SBOX in DES. I can't understand why they implement SBOX using & | operands. Maybe I have understood these tables incorrectly? I reviewed internet all morning and did not found any of example of SBOX's transformation with explanation (before/after SBOX values). Could you recommend any Crypto forum? Nobody answers on devshed

Comment: I already did: [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/).